# Can we have a memory leak while statically allocating memory?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

When we dynamically allocate memory and then do not release it back to the OS after consuming it, then a memory leak occurs. What is the case in static memory allocation?

Comment: @Paul R May it be C, C++ or Java.

Answer (score 1):

The process will always return the memory when it completes. This is actually a form of garbage collection that is available even to C and C++ programmers although many such people are purists and don't like to make use of it, in particular as it will show up as a leak in memory-checking programs.

The "real" definition of a leak is memory that you no longer want to use but is being consumed anyway, and in particular memory that is being constantly allocated such that you may run out of memory.

If you have a static cache and you add items to it and never remove them you will eventually run out of memory (if your cache is "unlimited") even if you are using a garbage-collected language as the memory is still considered "in use".

If your language is C++ and you use this kind of construct:

```
Foo& getTheFoo()
{
   static Foo theFoo;
   return theFoo;
}
```

this is a static allocation of an object. It will be cleaned up when your program exits and will call all its destructors. There can be a danger of doing this kind of thing in multiple places where you rely on the order of destruction. Also it might mean you get errors or your program may take a long time to exit (and we all know how much we hate apps that take enormous amounts of time to close down when we just want them to quit).

And therefore many prefer a "leaky" app which will simply use a pointer in the above situation. It isn't really a "leak" because the object pointed to is available to use when you need it and it will be cleaned up when your application quits just the way your "statically allocated" one will.

By the way, to get around your memory checker you can always have some kind of flag thus you have an object (yeah, a static one)

```
class FooDestructor
{
   public:
    ~FooDestructor()
    {
       if( usingMemoryChecker() )
         delete &getTheFoo(); // was allocated with new and not as static
    }
};

static FooDestructor fooDestructor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of "memory leak".  Very often, it is defined for the case where you have lost all pointers to some memory, so you are unable to free it, e.g.:

```
void *p = malloc(666);
p = NULL;
// Oh dear, can no longer call free on the memory!
```

Obviously, this situation doesn't occur for statically-allocated memory.

Comment: Does the same scenario happen when we use the new kyword in C++ for the above example?

Comment: Also what happens if a statically allocated memory is not released?

Comment: @Maxood: What does it mean for statically-allocated memory to be released?

Comment: Lets say i declare an array of int with a size of 5 values (int array[5]). I am staically allocating memory here. Can a memory leak occur here?